# Prove that $\sqrt{a}\leq\frac{1+a}{2}$

Tags: inequality

I have a math homework where it's being asked to prove that :

$$\forall a \geq 0,\sqrt{a}\leq\frac{1+a}{2}$$

However, I don't have any idea how I should start this one...

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you know the arithmetic mean- geometric mean inequality? If so, you can apply it directly to $1$ and $a$.

Comment: No I don't already know this one.

Comment: I like the geometric proof as in http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7c/SemicircleMeans.png

Comment: Seems really nice though I can't understand why the line is $\sqrt{ab}$ long

Comment: @Skydreamer, all triangles with a vertex on the semicircle and basis the diameter are right triangles and the square of the height is the product of the two parts, which follows from Pythagoras's Theorem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try expanding
$$
(\sqrt a - 1)^2 \geq 0
$$

Comment: Well, it was really simple... Sorry for the beginner's question.

Comment: That's OK - I have learned that, no matter how much I think I know about inequalities and how to prove them, what I don't know is far greater.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 7):

More generally, let $a,b\geq0$.

$$(a-b)^2 \geq0$$

$$a^2-2ab+b^2 \geq0$$

$$a^2+2ab+b^2 \geq 4ab$$

$$(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$$

$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \geq ab$$

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$