# Proving inequality using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm having some trouble proving the following inequality:

$$\sqrt x \leq \frac{x+1}{2}\ , \forall x \geq0$$

In this exercise, I'm supposed to use the mean value theorem. I always find myself having some trouble in these kinds of exercises. How can I prove this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191070 for alternative proofs.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equality holds for $x=1$, which suggests to use apply the mean value theorem to $f(x) - f(1)$ with $f(x) = \sqrt x$.

We get
$$
 \sqrt x - \sqrt 1 = (x-1) \frac{1}{2\sqrt c}
$$
for some $c$ between $1$ and $x$. Now consider the cases $0 \le x < 1$ and $x > 1$ and show that the right-hand side is always
$$
 \le \frac{x-1}{2} \, .
$$

(Note that we have essentially used is that the derivative of $f$ is decreasing. That is equivalent to $f$ being *concave* so that its graph lies below its tangent line at $x=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use MVT.
$$0\le(\sqrt x-1)^2=x-2\sqrt x+1 \iff 2\sqrt{x}\le x+1 \iff \sqrt{x}\le\frac{x+1}{2}$$
I use $x\ge0$ twice: first to be $\sqrt{x}$ well defined. Second, $(\sqrt{x})^2=|x|=x$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in this exercise I'm asked to use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \ge 0$ we have:

\begin{align}
\sqrt x \leq \frac{x+1}{2} &\iff x \le \frac{1}{4}(x+1)^2 \\&\iff 4x \le x^2+2x+1 \\&\iff 0 \le x^2-2x+1 \\&\iff 0 \le (x-1)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in this exercise I'm asked to use the mean value theorem.